# JavaScript added rows not accessible in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rows

I am making a web page in asp.net. I have created an HTML table with runat="server". I added some rows to it using JavaScript by getting values from input boxes. I need these rows accessible in code behind c#. When I use this table in code behind, it gives me just one row, which I added as a table heading in the HTML section. It does not consider the rows added in JavaScript. Is there any way to access these rows?

My HTML Code:

```
<table id="tblStaff" border="1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <th>S. No.</th>
        <th>Staff Name</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Phone No.</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function addStaff()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tblStaff');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
    var iteration = lastRow;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);           

    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
    cell0.appendChild(textNode);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('txtStaffName').value);
    cell1.appendChild(textNode);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    textNode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('txtRoomNo').value);
    cell2.appendChild(textNode);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    textNode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('txtPhoneNo').value);
    cell3.appendChild(textNode);

    var lastCell = row.insertCell(4);
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'button';
    el.name = 'btnDelete' + iteration;
    el.id = 'btnDelete' + iteration;
    el.value = 'Remove';
    el.size = 40;
    el.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(' + iteration + ');');
    lastCell.appendChild(el);         
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Also, a bit more detail. What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set runat="server" from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641804/set-runat-server-from-javascript)

Comment: I have shared the code. JavaScript function addStaff() is getting values from input boxes and adding rows to the HTML table. Now I want these rows accessible in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to let the user add some data via a form, then send it to the server and store it where you want. If this was successful, add the rerendered table to the response and render it on the client or add just the new row client side. On server side you cannot access the new rows, but you can access its data models, what should be sufficient.

If you want further advice you should elaborate on **why** you want to access those rows server side.

EDIT:
Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bauz4wvo/3/). There you see the structure your table has to be. Now if you want to add an user, just add a new row in this format with `index` of users in `name` incremented. Now if you hit submit, all users will be send as an array to the server where you can iterate through them and send an email.

You web api method could look like:

```
//route url/to/api
public void AddNewUser(User[] users) 
{
   //iterate through users and send email
}
```

Comment: Actually the requirement of application is to create a large number of staff members. When a staff member is created, not only its data will be stored into database, but also a notification email will be sent. If we create individual users, then for each user we have to wait. I want that we put all the staff members once into a table using JavaScript and then let all these go to database and email notification system once.

Comment: You could also add a flag to the user table, let's say `notificated` and set it to false when you add a new user. Then, on some trigger (specific time, press a button, etc.), select all users whose `notificated` flag is set to false, send the email and set `notificated` to true.

Comment: There is, have a look at my edit. But have in mind with this method, all data will be lost when refreshing the page. Lets say, you add 20 users, do not submit and accidentaly hit F5, all users will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your addStaff() function only adds to the table in the frontend. If I may point out, the C# is executed server side, and so, the rows added by your javascript do not exist at the time when your C# is looking for them.

Like Florian Gl suggested, you could include an ajax submit in your addStaff() function, that also sends whatever row the javascript displays in the table in the browser, to the C# in the backend. Once you have the data in your C#, you can proceed with sending the email or can even opt to save a database...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

 foreach (HtmlTableRow row in tblStaff.Rows)
          {
            string txtCell0 = row.Cells[0].InnerText; 
            string txtCell1 = row.Cells[1].InnerText; 
          }
```

Comment: You cannot access the Rows Added via java script because on postback the manipulated DOM is lost. May be you should try using AJAX